# OS-specific parts in documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

Some parts of documentation depend on the operating system. For example, [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/node.js/340/hello-world/1443/hello-world-command-line#t=201607211125061077733) does not help a Windows user at all. It says to use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` as the first line of a JavaScript script to create a command-line utility. Which works fine on UNIX-like systems, but it doesn't result in an executable file on Windows.

So here are a few possibilities how these cases of OS-specific details could be handled:

- Assume that everyone uses Linux. And [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29). Or should we assume UNIX-like systems? [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-compliant ones? POSIX-compliant shells? Why not Windows as the default?
- Provide instructions for each (major) OS in each concrete example.
- Provide one example per OS.
- Only name the general, OS-independent concept (e.g. 'make a file executable') without providing OS-specific details. But where can these be looked up? Externally? Or can this be standardized?
- Add OS-awareness to the documentation system (no, please don't).

There are obvious problems with all of these, but finding a consistent solution across documentation could be helpful.

Also, should there even be guidelines on this? Is this a valid reason to downvote?